# Change the Statusbar text color to black when the Statusbar background is white

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I have tried tried a few solutions given here but none seems to work for me. This is what I have in my colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#fcfdfb</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#333</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryText">#333</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

And this is what I have in styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
<style name="ProDialogue" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
<style name="TransparentToolbar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I just need the Statusbar text/icons to be black because I have the background as white to match the content. As a beginner, I am sure that I've messed it up somewhere but hopefully someone will guide me on this. Btw, my minSdkVersion is 21.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add these attributes to your theme

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
```

Note this only works on 23+, so you'll have to make a 23+ theme file with these attributes. I'm fairly sure that < 23 every device's status bar is black and white  and you can't change that, but you should double check

Comment: This worked for me after changing the minSdkVersion to 23. Thank you.

Comment: @dspblack You don't have to change it to 23, you can create a second theme file in a values-v23 folder and use it in there. That way it works on 23 and below. I'm fairly certain the reason you can't change the status bar text color < 23 is because all devices use the standard black and white status bar at that version